# Como exibir "de" dentro do DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, datepicker

No `DateTimePicker` eu posso exibir qualquer coisa utilizando `d` para dia, `MM` ou `MMMM` para mês e `yy` ou `yyyy` para ano.

Porém, gostaria de simplesmente exibir na propriedade `customformat`: 15 de abril.

Porém, quando escrevo:

```
dtApartir.CustomFormat = "d de MMMM de yyyy";
```

Resulta em:

> 15 15e abril 15e 2014.

Existe alguma forma de contornar isso e exibir o "d" do "de"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aspas símples dentro da string, tal como se fossem substrings:

```
dtApartir.CustomFormat = "d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy";
```

Comment: Funcionou, assim que liberar marco como certa (:

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`barra invertida \\`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#escape).

> Para evitar que um caractere seja interpretado como um especificador
>   de formato, você pode precedê-lo com uma barra invertida `\\`, que é o
>   caractere de escape.
>
> O caractere de escape significa que o seguinte é
>   um caractere literal que deve ser incluído na sequência de resultado
>   inalterado.

Faça assim:

```
 dtApartir.CustomFormat = "d \\de MMMM \\de yyyy";
```

Comment: Retornou o erro: Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: Para usar essa solução, você teria que fazer assim: `@"d \de MMMM \de yyyy"`, ou então `"d \\de MMMM \\de yyyy"`.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece pois o C# interpreta a letra 'd' da palavra "de" como se fosse a letra '**d**' reservada para o formato do número do dia.

Não esqueça de setar o **Format**, também:

```
dtApartir.CustomFormat = String.Format("d {0} MMMM {0}", "'de'");
dtApartir.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```